# MySQL in Android

Tags: android, mysql

I am new to Android Development. I have created an application Which stores the name and age in mysql database.

Now I want to retrieving that name and age from the database and display it in `ListView`. I tried the `HttpPost` method for retrieving but I am not able to do that.

Comment: Are you using some web interface to transfer data between your MySql server located somewhere on the Internet and your Android application?
Aren't you using any scripting language in between?

Comment: I am assuming that you aren't referring to Android local database, that is SQLite, and not MySql

Answer (score 1):

For an internet server: Try making a wrapper in PHP that gives back XML or JSON as output. Then use a HTTP request to get the XML / JSON output.

For a local persistent storage: Maby check out this [Android tutorial](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-simple-but-persistent-data-storage/).